# I have a Spanish infix

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

> My prefix is where you are now at, 
>    I have a Spanish infix. 
>    With a double L to my last two letters, 
>    You might want to sell your homophone. 
>    In order for the word to make sense, 
>    Put n.

What word am I?

Clue 1: (Given 11 hours later)

> What?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With majority credit to the previous answer, you must be

> **SEQUENCE**

*My prefix is where you are now at,*

> We are all on "SE-" i.e. Stack Exchange, as previously noted

*I have a Spanish infix.*

> "-QUE-" is Spanish for "what", explaining the first clue

*With a double L to my last two letters,

You might want to sell your homophone.*

> Add two L's to "-CE" and you get "CELL", a homophone of "sell"

*In order for the word to make sense,

Put n.*

> Not sure of this one, but a mathematical sequence must be defined by index "n" to make any sense. *Edit: as per the comments below, this line simply indicates to add "n" to "SE-QUE-CE" to complete the construction of "SE-QUE-N-CE".*

Comment: Actually, I think the N clue just indicates rot13(gb nqq gur yrggre A va gur jbeq, fvapr gur cnegvny jbeqf ner FR, DHR naq PR).

Comment: I like that explanation. It's much tighter. Thanks @Enzo

Comment: Huh ... that means the OP [originally included the solution in the title of the question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/94062/revisions). Very weird indeed. By accident?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes, it was really by accident as I was referring to the word while typing out the riddle :P :(

Comment: @UnidentifiedX oooops :-P actually I wondered what that word was doing in the title, but didn't even consider (because it was there) that it might be the solution!

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> SELL?

*My prefix is where you are now at,*

> SE (i.e. Stack Exchange).

*I have a Spanish infix.*

> EL (a common Spanish word).

*With a double L to my suffix,*

> Your suffix is literally double L.

*You might want to sell your homophone.*

> Including the solution word in the puzzle itself, this could be what we used to call a "lynch mob" clue. Maybe "homophone" is a double pun, based on the homophone "cell" being put together with "phone" as another word.

Comment: Well, that's not what the word is, but you have some clues that is actually part of the answer, but you haven't got there yet :D